# How to Stop the Dragging the Thumb In the Progress Bar In Input Field

Tags: angular

In the Progress Bar I need to Stop the Dragging by Mannuly It should Be IN automatically In angular  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HauCW.png)

the Dragging Should Not be there In the angular Code Can Plz say How to Fix this Issue In The Angular Code

Comment: please describe your problem properly Im unable to understand you issue.